# How to get Current Date time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetime

How can I get current date and time in `angularjs`

I have tried the following:

```
<b>{{Date.Now}}</b>
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define getDatetime method on scope

```
scope.getDatetime = function() {
  return (new Date).toLocaleFormat("%A, %B %e, %Y");
};
```

Then in template:

```
<b>{{getDatetime()}}</b>
```

Doc to format date https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat

Comment: It is what i want to do. Sorry i can't click up vote.

Comment: @user2998788 use toLocaleFormat to format datetime. See updated answer

Answer (score 21):

Thanks all I got it by your all of answer

```
<b>{{getDatetime | date:'yyyy-MMM-dd'}}</b>
```

In controller, 
`$scope.getDatetime = new Date();`

Answer (score 5):

In your controller

```
scope.v.Dt = Date.now();
```

The DOM syntax is

```
{{v.Dt | date:'medium'}}
```

For an example -

Output - 
`Oct 28, 2010 8:40:23 PM`

Answer (score 3):

In your controller -
    scope.v.Dt = Date.now();

The DOM syntax is -

```
{{v.Dt | date:'medium'}}
```

For an example -

```
Output - 
Oct 28, 2010 8:40:23 PM
```

For all possible date formats - 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Comment: But How can i give the value for `timestamp ` ?

Comment: Added explanation. Have a look

Comment: I added the details... have a look.

Answer (score 3):

In Component file:

```
this.registerDate = new Date().toJSON("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
this.updateDate = new Date().toJSON("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
```

In Template file:

```
<span class="font-size-13px">{{registerDate}}</span>
<span class="font-size-13px">{{updateDate}}</span>
```

Result will return:
[image]

Comment: thanks, this is the modern way to do it. much easier. by the way, this link provides the online way of formatting Date object into different string. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-format-dates-in-javascript/#:~:text=Conclusion,%2B0100%20(British%20Summer%20Time)