# in angular js - how get current time on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time

I have two buttons like in and out, i need to show current time .. once clicked any button i need to send current time and date

```
 <label>Today's Date : {{currentdate}}</label>
  <label>Current Time :  {{currenttime}}</label>

  <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="disabledin"  value="in" ng-
  click="submitFun($event)">IN</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-disabled="disabledout" value="out" 
   ng-click="submitFun($event)">OUT</button>
```

Comment: send time and date where?

Comment: have you tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013685/how-to-get-current-date-time to get current date and time

Comment: Ya i have tried that one @warl0ck

Comment: to the back end @ ananthhh

Comment: i am getting time and date .but only refreshing page i am getting different  time ..

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.someFunction = function() {
      $scope.date = new Date();
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <pre>current date: {{date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</pre>
  <pre>time: {{date | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}</pre>
  <button ng-click="someFunction()">show date time</button>
</body>
```

Comment: why to use this $scope.currentDate = date.getDate() + " / " + date.getMonth() + " / " + date.getFullYear()....where you can simply use the date filter in html???

Comment: ya but time should be take dynamic @Sa E Chowdary

Comment: @user123 time is dynamic here. try clicking the button more than once seperated by a few seconds. or you want dynamic time formats?

Answer (score 0):

what about `var time = new Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can use:

```
$scope.submitFun($event){
    $scope.currentDate = new Date();
    $scope.currentTime = new Date().getTime();
}
```

And you can change date format with filter in your html:

```
<label>Today's Date : {{currentdate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</label>
```

Read some [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Your  $scope.currentTime = new Date().getTime(); will return something like 1492410436254 which is not a user understandable time

Comment: @SaEChowdary It is actıual time. If developer wants to see a date he/she can use filters.

Comment: Yes but the OP asked about both data and time of current...so what i am asking is show how to do that also as you did for current date

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    function checkTime(i) {
        return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date(),
        $scope.currentdate = today;
            h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
            m = checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
            s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());
        $scope.currenttime = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    startTime();
})();
```

Comment: It is not an angular way! Angular way is date filter! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date