# angularjs show last render time not working

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I am going to debug my existing program so I added showing last time method.
Code

```
 <h1>
 Time is {{date | date: "medium" }}
 </h1>

  $scope.date = function(){
    Date.now();
  }
```

But not showing any result.

reference 
[How to get Current Date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013685/how-to-get-current-date-time)

fsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/b6xgjfwg/13/

So How can I show the last rendered time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `$scope.date` is a function, so call it as such

   ```
   {{date() | date: 'medium'}}
   ```
2. `$scope.date` doesn't return anything. Fix it

   ```
   $scope.date = function() { return Date.now() }
   // Note the "return" ------^
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/b6xgjfwg/14/